# Сортировка вычисляемого столбца

Tags: delphi

Доброго времени суток.

На форме имеется компонент IBQuery. В запросе пишу.

```
select a,b
from priv
```

Поле a и b у меня типа float. Дальше я добавил вычисляемое поле s (в нем находится результат a*b) к моему IBQuery и вот его-то и нужно отсортировать по возрастанию. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно выполнить сортировку этого поля.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select a, b, a*b from priv order by 3
```

А по Calculated Field - никак.

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня как раз Calculated Field

Answer (score 2):

Возможно так?:

```
select a, b, a*b as ab from priv order by ab
```

Comment: В oracle работает

Comment: Сортировка Calculated Field у меня не получилась, буду переделывать, что бы непосредственно перемноженные данные в носились в таблицу, а потом их сортировать. Спасибо за ответ.